# Feedback ao usuário

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

tenho um método em php que executa determinada tarefa e em seguida, preciso dar um feedback de sucesso/erro ao usuário e retornar ao meu index.php. Este feedback pode ocorrer tanto antes de retornar quanto em meu próprio index.php. Meu atual cenário é o seguinte:

```
$conexao->setSQL("INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('x');
$resultado = $conexao->Executar();  


$erroRegistros = $totalRegistros - $adicRegistros;

if(!$resultado){
   die("erro in uploading the file".  mysql_error());
} else{
    // FEEDBACK NECESSÁRIO E RETORNO AO MEU INDEX
    voltarIndex();
}
```

Nesta classe, existem apenas códigos em php. Já na minha index.php há códigos html, javascript e inclusive, php.

Para via de dúvidas, meu método voltarIndex() segue abaixo:

```
function voltarIndex() {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: O `index.php` é um formulário?

Comment: minha página inicial, contendo diversos botões, tabelas e afins

Comment: Se possível poste o parte do formulário responsável por enviar o `post`, daí posso complementar minha resposta com `javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `XMLHttpRequest` para fazer uma requisição sem sair da página e ao fim dessa, exibir uma mensagem para o usuário; ou você pode utilizar `Sessions` para salvar uma mensagem e ao retornar para `index.php`, exibir a mensagem.

#### Exemplo com Sessions:

**adiciona-registro.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$conexao->setSQL("INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('x')");
$resultado = $conexao->Executar();  


$erroRegistros = $totalRegistros - $adicRegistros;

if(!$resultado){
    $_SESSION["feedback"] = "Erro in uploading the file" . mysql_error();
} else{
    $_SESSION["feedback"] = "Digite sua mensagem aqui";
}

voltarIndex();
```

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE hml>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        Página inicial
        Diversos botões
        tabelas
        afins

        <div class="msg"><?php echo (isset($_SESSION["feedback"])) ? $_SESSION["feedback"]; unset($_SESSION["feedback"]) : "" ?></div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Lembrando que `session_start();` deve ficar no topo.